# Why keyboard event function of "Enter" button is not working;

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, appendchild, queryselector

I have the following very simple HTML
AND at the if statement at js script I am just trying to insert an additional functionality when someone enters the "Enter" button - but Idk WHY it's not working!

```js
document.querySelector(".subText").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    let x = document.querySelector("#fname").value;
    console.log(x);
  }
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="toDo">
        <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ionicon" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            <path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32" d="M224 184h128m-128 72h128m-128 71h128"/>
            <path d="M448 258c0-106-86-192-192-192S64 152 64 258s86 192 192 192 192-86 192-192z" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="32"/>
            <circle cx="168" cy="184" r="8" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32"/>
            <circle cx="168" cy="257" r="8" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32"/>
            <circle cx="168" cy="328" r="8" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32"/>
          </svg> -->
        <p class="toDoText">To-do List</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="I need to..." class="inputText">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="subText" onclick="addNote()">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <!-- <div class="notesList">
          <p class="notesInput">ddbd</p>
          <button class="deleteBut" onclick="deleFunc()">
          </button>
        </div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function *is* called and the `if` statement executed correctly.
Here, I've edited the `console.log` lines.

Run the snippet.
Click the text box, use the tab key to select the button, then hit the enter key.
Et voila! 3 `console.log` statements run.

Perhaps you need to refine your understanding of what's happening and from that, your question. :)

```js
document.querySelector(".subText").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    let x = document.querySelector("#fname").value;
//        console.log(x);
    console.log("console.log(x); (1)");
  }
});

function addNote() {
  let x = document.querySelector("#fname").value;
//        console.log(x);
    console.log("console.log(x); (2)");
  let divN = document.createElement("div");
  divN.classList.add("notesList");
  let para = document.createElement("p");
  para.classList.add("notesInput");
  divN.appendChild(para);
  let paraText = document.createTextNode(x);
//      console.log(paraText);
    console.log("console.log(paraText); (3)");
  para.appendChild(paraText);
  let but = document.createElement("button");
  but.classList.add("deleteBut");
  but.setAttribute("onclick", "deleFunc()")
  divN.appendChild(but);
  let y = document.querySelector(".test");
  y.appendChild(divN);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="toDo">
        <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ionicon" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            <path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32" d="M224 184h128m-128 72h128m-128 71h128"/>
            <path d="M448 258c0-106-86-192-192-192S64 152 64 258s86 192 192 192 192-86 192-192z" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="32"/>
            <circle cx="168" cy="184" r="8" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32"/>
            <circle cx="168" cy="257" r="8" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32"/>
            <circle cx="168" cy="328" r="8" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32"/>
          </svg> -->
        <p class="toDoText">To-do List</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="I need to..." class="inputText">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="subText" onclick="addNote()">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <!-- <div class="notesList">
          <p class="notesInput">ddbd</p>
          <button class="deleteBut" onclick="deleFunc()">
          </button>
        </div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you @enhzflep for your time. The problem with the second question had to do with the property of width at last but the solution for the first it works only if I initially press submit. If I change the input again I am still not able to use "Enter"

Answer (score 0):

> With the if statement I am just trying to insert an additional functionality when someone enters the "Enter" button - Idk WHY it's not working!

You added the listener on the button, instead of adding a listener to the input field.

> and with the rest of the code inside addNote() function, I am trying to create an element every time the user inserts a new input -similar to that, which is commented out at HTML code. However, it seems that styling from the element generated from JS just breaks in contrary with the div I have commented out in HTML...

I rearranged your code, so it's more readable. I would suggest to refactor each creation and attribute changes for each element to methods of their own, to make the code even more readable.

During my rearrangement, I automatically solved your problem, by putting the code in the right order. Now the generated code looks like your commented code.

I also added an event listener to your button. If you remove the button, you need to remove the event listener too, otherwise there will be a memory leak.

---

I would also like to suggest that you start using `id` and `getElementByID` instead of `querySelect` and `class`, just to create a pattern where `id` on an element indirectly says that it's used together with javascript.

```js
document.getElementById("fname").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    addNote();
  }
});

function addNote() {
  let x = document.querySelector("#fname");
  let divN = document.createElement("div");
  let para = document.createElement("p");
  let paraText = document.createTextNode(x.value);
  let but = document.createElement("button");
  let y = document.querySelector(".test");

  x.value = '';

  divN.classList.add("notesList");
  para.classList.add("notesInput");
  but.classList.add("deleteBut");
  
  but.addEventListener('click', (event) =>
    { console.log('clicked removed') }
  );
  
  divN.appendChild(para);
  para.appendChild(paraText);
  divN.appendChild(but);
  y.appendChild(divN);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="toDo">
        <!-- <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ionicon" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            <path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32" d="M224 184h128m-128 72h128m-128 71h128"/>
            <path d="M448 258c0-106-86-192-192-192S64 152 64 258s86 192 192 192 192-86 192-192z" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="32"/>
            <circle cx="168" cy="184" r="8" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32"/>
            <circle cx="168" cy="257" r="8" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32"/>
            <circle cx="168" cy="328" r="8" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32"/>
          </svg> -->
        <p class="toDoText">To-do List</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="I need to..." class="inputText">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="subText" onclick="addNote()">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test">
      <!-- <div class="notesList">
          <p class="notesInput">ddbd</p>
          <button class="deleteBut" onclick="deleFunc()">
          </button>
        </div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: indeed! It is more readable now! @RichardElimaa thank you very much for your note. The problem with the second question had to do with the property of width at last but the solution for the first works only if I initially press submit. If I change the input again I am still not able to use "Enter"

Comment: OK, but my answer solved that, right? I made a small correction in the code, where the input is cleared after adding an item to the list (when hitting Enter or the button).

Comment: unfortunately not, because if I write something at input and I press enter no element is created

Comment: Weird, because my snippet works for me, both in Mac Firefox and Mac Chrome.

Comment: I don't press submit with the "enter" button. I just write something in the input and then I press enter. Probably what are you saying is different.

Comment: We're talking about the same behavior - can you click on the grey "delete button" to see the console.log message? I forgot to mention this, but `keyCode` shouldn't be used any longer, so I changed the method in the listener to check `key` instead.